# __invoke in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I want to split my codebase to simple one purpose specific classes like:

```
class AddKeyword
{
    /**
     * @var KeywordRepository
     */
    private $keywordRepository;

    public function __construct(KeywordRepository $keywordRepository)
    {
        $this->keywordRepository = $keywordRepository;
    }

    public function __invoke(string $name): Keyword
    {
        $entity = $this->keywordRepository->findOneByName($name);

        if ($entity)
            return $entity;

        $entity = Keyword::create(KeywordId::create(), $name);
        $this->keywordRepository->save($entity);

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

But for using that class I have to resolve DI. How to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you want to achieve but if you want add/get keyword everywhere in your code base you have 2 choices:

- Use autowiring
- Declare your class as service and get it from the container.

Symfony encourage DI by autowiring.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\AddKeyword;

class DefaultController
{
    public function __construct(Addkeyword $keyword) {
        $keyword('keyword');
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But if I do it in that way
```
    public function __construct(AddKeyword $addKeywordService)
    {
        $this->addKeywordService = $addKeywordService;
    }

    public function __invoke(ScanKeywordPositionsCommand $command)
    {
        $keyword = $this->addKeywordService($command->keyword);
    }
```
I get   Attempted to call an undefined method named "addKeywordService" of class "App\Domain\Keyword\Command\Scan\ScanKeywordPositionsHandler"

Comment: Sorry for ugly comment. I could not figure out how to post well formatting code in comment :(

Comment: Well is not a symfony issue but a PHP implementation problem when. You can't call nested `__invoke` function if you store the first object as property of the second. Test this code in a phpsandbox you'll see: https://codeshare.io/G8kmOe. Also you should avoid the usage of PHP magic function, it can be confusing, it's difficult to maintain due to overhead and isn't that well supported by IDE. They can be powerfull but they need a really good understanding of their utilities, interpretations and limitations